# The usage of Zorn's lemma

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I tried to summarize the usage of Zorn's lemma using the insight earned from proofs of 'Zorn's lemma implies AC' and 'Zorn's lemma implies the well-ordering theorem.' Please check if the followings are reasonable.

**When to use Zorn's lemma:**
To show the existence of a desired binary relation (function or partial order) on a set $X$.

**How to use Zorn's lemma:**

1. Form a pair
   $$
   (S, R)
   $$
   where $S$ is a subset of $X$ and $R$ is a binary relation of our interest on $S$.
2. Form the set $T$ of all such pairs.
3. Define a partial order on $T$. (The order can be based on an initial segment if $R$ is a well order on $S$ for $(S, R) \in T$)
4. Show that every chain of $T$ has an upper bound in $T$.
5. Let $(M, R_M)$ be the maximal element of $T$ obtained by Zorn's lemma. Show that $X = M$ through a proof by $\bot$: Suppose $M \subsetneq X$ and construct a set $M'$ and extended relation $R'$ on $M'$ formed by adding an element $x \notin M$ to $M$ as a strict upper bound of $M$.

Please see if there is an invalid statement. Is this a usual strategy for Zorn's lemma?

Comment: Seems reasonable. One of the big hangups regarding Zorn's lemma I've seen from newbies are the words "upper bound" and "maximal". Depending on the ordering you chose, a "maximal" element might just be the smallest element in your set. As long as you understand that, this is a fair summary.

Comment: @DonThousand Yes, it can be indeed. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Of course Zorn's Lemma is sometimes used for things other than these.   It is interesting to investigate what result this was a lemma for.